# Mysql table disappear after reset of AUTO_INCREMENT

Tags: mysql

Mysql table disappear after reset of AUTO_INCREMENT. Here is procedure that I use to reset the auto_increment field. Why it's disappeared ? What I'm doing wrong. When I check the /var/lib/mysql/database_name I see file for that table !

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS set_auto_increment;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE set_auto_increment (_table VARCHAR(64), _inc INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE _stmt VARCHAR(1024);
    SET @SQL := CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', _table, ' AUTO_INCREMENT =  ', _inc);
    PREPARE _stmt FROM @SQL;
    EXECUTE _stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE _stmt;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

I'm doing :

```
select max(id)
  into p_max
  from table_name;

if p_max is not null then
    call set_auto_increment('table_name',p_max);
end if;
```

Comment: Obviously this should not make the table disappear, can you show the console log of the table existing, running the SP, and the result where you determined it was missing?

Comment: may you share all files names related with this table in db directory and what was the engine of this table....assuming id (from where getting max(id)) will be integer type.